Losing user authentication when returning from opened application tab
I have an application called Portal with a backend in Ruby on Rails and frontend in Vue.js. This application works as follows: the user authenticates, and on the main page, the applications they have access to are loaded. When the user clicks on one of the applications, it opens in a new tab, and the user is automatically authenticated in it. Therefore, its operation is like a hyperlink to facilitate user access to the company's applications.
The second application that opens also has a backend in Ruby on Rails and frontend in Vue.js and shares the same JWT authentication API with the first application. Note: in our company's applications, the same user has different profiles according to the application they are in, so they necessarily need to authenticate in both to access these functionalities.
I am able to make the first application open the second application using the window.open() function in JavaScript, passing the URL and user data as parameters in the URL. When opening the new tab in the second application, the frontend captures these parameters and authenticates the user, then redirects them to the initial page. My problem arises when I return to the first application; I lose the user in my backend (frontend recognizes it normally). My controller no longer recognizes the user, and I'm not exactly sure what's happening.
This is a summary of my problem. Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?
I have tried creating a re-login function in the first application after calling the window.open() function, but I haven't been successful.
I expected that the backend of my first application wouldn't lose access to the user.
Could anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this or suggest what might be causing the backend of my first application to lose access to the user after opening the second application?
Edit 1: Edit to post part of the authentication code for both applications
This is the function of my controller for user authentication in application 1
module Api
 module V1
   class SessoesController < ActionController::API
    include ::CasacivilgoPermissoes::SessaoApi

     def autenticar
      resposta = login_helper
      render json: resposta, status: resposta[:code]
     end
    end
  end
end

This is the login_helper function that is called by the controller and it is already part of the API shared with application 2
require 'net/http'
require 'casacivilgo_permissoes/usuario'

module CasacivilgoPermissoes
 module SessaoApi
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include CasacivilgoPermissoes::JwToken

  def login_helper
   if ::CasacivilgoPermissoes.configuration.sgu_url.blank?
    raise CasacivilgoPermissoes::Errors::ConfigConstantMissing, 
      'CasacivilgoPermissoes.configuration.sgu_url não está 
       configurada'
   end
   if ::CasacivilgoPermissoes.configuration.sistema_sigla.blank?
    raise CasacivilgoPermissoes::Errors::ConfigConstantMissing, 
      'CasacivilgoPermissoes.configuration.sistema_sigla não está 
      configurada'
   end

   login = params.dig(:login)&.strip
   response = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI("http://localhost:3001/acesso_externo/api/v1/autenticacao/login"), 
    login: login, senha: params[:senha], sistema: ::CasacivilgoPermissoes.configuration.sistema_sigla)
  if response.code == '200'
    parsed_body = JSON.parse response.body
    usuario = ::CasacivilgoPermissoes::Usuario.new parsed_body
    generate_auth_cookie(usuario)

    { usuario: usuario.to_hash, sucesso: true, code: 200 }
  else
    format_error(response)
   end
  end
 end
end

Here begins the token generation, encoding and decoding algorithm (Some keys I placed * to preserve confidentiality)
require 'jwt'

module CasacivilgoPermissoes
module JwToken
 extend ActiveSupport::Concern
 include CasacivilgoPermissoes::Helpers

 ALGORITMO_JWT = 'HS***'.freeze
 ISS = 'Se******** da **** ***** do ****** de *****'.freeze

def criar_token(usuario, v_key)
  validar_secret_key_jwt

  payload = { exp: expire_in(usuario).to_i,
              iss: ISS, iat: Time.now.to_i, usuario: 
            usuario.to_hash, v_key: v_key }

  JWT.encode payload, CasacivilgoPermissoes.configuration.secret_key_jwt, ALGORITMO_JWT
end

def decodificar_token(private_token, public_token)
  validar_secret_key_jwt

  leeway = 30 # seconds

  begin
    token = JWT.decode(private_token, CasacivilgoPermissoes.configuration.secret_key_jwt, true,
                       { algorithm: ALGORITMO_JWT, exp_leeway: leeway, iss: ISS, verify_iss: true,
                         verify_iat: true })
    raise CasacivilgoPermissoes::Errors::InvalidAuthToken if token.first&.dig('v_key') != public_token

    token
  rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature, JWT::InvalidIatError
    raise CasacivilgoPermissoes::Errors::Unauthenticated
  rescue JWT::ImmatureSignature, JWT::InvalidIssuerError, JWT::InvalidAudError,
         JWT::InvalidJtiError, JWT::InvalidSubError
   
    raise CasacivilgoPermissoes::Errors::Unauthenticated
  rescue JWT::DecodeError, 
       CasacivilgoPermissoes::Errors::InvalidAuthToken
    raise CasacivilgoPermissoes::Errors::Unauthenticated
  end
end

def generate_auth_cookie(usuario)
  expiration_time = expire_in(usuario)
  if usuario.present?
    v_key = SecureRandom.hex
    cookies[:auth_private] =
      { value: criar_token(usuario, v_key), httponly: true, 
      expires: expiration_time, domain: request&.host }
    cookies.signed.encrypted[:auth_public] =
      { value: v_key, httponly: false, expires: expiration_time, 
      domain: request&.host }
  end
end

def validar_secret_key_jwt
  if CasacivilgoPermissoes.configuration.secret_key_jwt.blank?
    raise ::CasacivilgoPermissoes::Errors::ConfigConstantMissing,
          'CasacivilgoPermissoes.configuration.secret_key_jwt não 
          encontrada'
   end
  end
 end
end

And here begins application authentication 2:
def login_token_jwt_helper
  if ::CasacivilgoPermissoes.configuration.sgu_url.blank?
    raise CasacivilgoPermissoes::Errors::ConfigConstantMissing, 'CasacivilgoPermissoes.configuration.sgu_url não está configurada'
  end
  if ::CasacivilgoPermissoes.configuration.sistema_sigla.blank?
    raise CasacivilgoPermissoes::Errors::ConfigConstantMissing, 'CasacivilgoPermissoes.configuration.sistema_sigla não está configurada'
  end
  if params.dig(:params).dig(:tokenPrivado)&.strip.blank? || params.dig(:params).dig(:tokenPublico)&.strip.blank?
    raise CasacivilgoPermissoes::Errors::ConfigConstantMissing, 'Token de segurança não está configurado'
  end

  login = params.dig(:params).dig(:login)&.strip
  sistema = params.dig(:params).dig(:sistemaSigla)&.strip
  token_privado = params.dig(:params).dig(:tokenPrivado)&.strip
  token_publico = params.dig(:params).dig(:tokenPublico)&.strip

  token_autorizado = decodificar_token(token_privado, token_publico);

  if token_autorizado
    
    response = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI("http://localhost:3001/acesso_externo/api/v1/autenticacao/login_token_jwt"), 
    login: login, token: token_autorizado, sistema: sistema)
  else
    raise CasacivilgoPermissoes::Errors::Unauthenticated
  end  

  if response.code == '200'
    parsed_body = JSON.parse response.body
    novoUsuario = ::CasacivilgoPermissoes::Usuario.new parsed_body
    generate_auth_cookie(novoUsuario)

    { usuario: novoUsuario.to_hash, sucesso: true, code: 200 }
  else
    format_error(response)
  end
end

Here is some of the code that the two applications use, some functions they share with each other and in application 2, as mentioned, the frontend when called by application 1 is automatically called, which ends up calling the login_token_jwt_helper function

Given this statement "shares the same JWT authentication API with the first application" is it possible when you authenticate in application 2 you are overwriting the cookie that stores the JWT Token and thus invalidating the application 1 session? You are likely going to have to provide some code/error messages for this process or it is unlikely we will be able to assist pass guessing.

I'm getting a 403 error code in my backend. When I do a console.log in my localStorage I can see that the browser is correctly saving my user, that is, apparently in my browser's cookies, application 1 is still recognizing the user normally, but my backend is not. Thanks for the answer!

Yes, the backends share the same database, but I'm not saving that JWT token in the database. And yes, if I log into application 1 again I lose access to application 2

Parts of the code and explanation of each one were included in the post edit

I see potentially 2 issues (although that is a lot of code to dive through). 1) generate_auth_cookie overwrites the existing cookies so each login stomps on the last one. 2) While the applications may share the same code you are generating a new v_key in generate_auth_cookie each time and then using this to validate the login token.first&.dig('v_key') != public_token

So what would be the most viable solution to correct this overwrite? And about v_key, I didn't really understand its impact. Could I just remove the generate_auth_cookie for the second application?

I managed to find a solution through your help. Thank you very much enginerrsmnky!
